# Security cameras on IPV6

Tags: ipv6, ip-camera, ddns

This is really a two part question.

First the problem: HughesNet provides ONLY IPv6 access.  They do NAT your local network and even provide an IPv4 address.  But the IPv4 address is for looks only - you cannot route to it.

This causes a LOT of problems, some small, some apparently insurmountable.  The relatively simple goal is to be able to view my cameras when not at home.

HughesNet has defeated the whole reason for IPV6's existence by laying CGN (carrier grade NAT) on top of it.  Thus your IPV6 address is constantly changing.  The obvious solution is DDNS.  But it appears there are no cameras or routers on the market that will update IPv6 DDNS.  This is the real problem.  Finding one that would update DDNS would fix everything else.

Without DDNS another option is a cloud service.  Note that I don't expect FIOS performance.  But I do have a somewhat respectable 3/10 (up/down) service that was quite acceptable back when I had a routable address.

One of my cameras is a FOSCAM.  I attached it to their service.  The results are nothing short of horrifying.  Half the time the connection times out the rest of the time pan / tilt is a joke with 2 minute+ repaint time.  I just got a TRENDLINE camera and am going to see if their cloud is any better.  But I fear it won't be the 10,000 times better needed to make it up to usable.

Finally there are the commercial offerings.  But there are surprisingly few and the one I talked to said if you don't have unlimited internet they won't even sell to you.

I haven't found any combination of infrastructure that can be made to work without a lot of custom programming on my part.  I may have to try to do something with a Raspberry PI.  Any other ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't look like you have an actual question as there isn't a single question mark in your "question". Why would you not let your router handle DDNS and connect through it?

Comment: There are 4 questions in decreasing order of preference.  1) Does anyone know a piece of hardware that will update IPV6 DDNS?  Note NOT a PC program.  A piece of hardware.   2) Does anyone know a cloud based camera service that is actually any good?  For reference FOSCAM is not "any good".  3) Does anyone know a commercial service that will work with limited bandwidth?  This might be even better but it appears there are none. 4) Any other ideas I haven't considered?  I.E. Does anyone have IPV6 cameras working on CGN?

Comment: Why would you not add them to your actual question? Part 1-3 are considered [off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) as shopping recommendations. The hardware recommendation exchange might be a better place for that. As for 4 see my first comment.

Comment: It seemed crystal clear to me as it was before you edited the question -- a feature of Stack Exchange that is easily abused IMO.  Do you have any constructive, non-editorial, suggestions?

Comment: Use your router to do the DDNS part and access your webcams through that instead of directly. Use a VPN using a cheap VPS or use one of the commercial offers. As you already note you're behind a CGN so your options are limited and it will usually be easier to establish a connection from the inside to the outside. As for your changing IP make sure what part you're looking at. If it's within your network your cameras might be using the privacy extension. You're dissatisfied with your ISP but it doesn't add anything to the "question" so I removed the snark. Feel free to Rollback.

Comment: These are remote cameras that we only visit every few months.  Also it isn't uncommon to have fairly long power outages, which is why most PC based solutions won't work.  The new Trendline router I got doesn't really support IPV6 like the tech sheet, and support Chat said and it completely fails to update DDNS.  BUT it does have a VPN.  I possibly could set up a VPN from there to home.  Thus basically bridging the networks.  There are some obvious problems with that plan.  But it is indeed a 4th option.

Comment: https://community.hughesnet.com/t5/Tech-Support/HT2000W-IPv6-inbound-services/td-p/83342/page/7 and dump Hughes if you can.